# Some questions about learning commutative algebra

Tags: commutative-algebra, learning

Does anyone knows some good methods for learning commutative algebra? I'm having a tough time learning Matsumura's commutative ring theory; it seems he uses some tricks of homological algebra which I'm quite unfamiliar with.

Comment: Outside of finding other resources to give additional clarity and making sure you work lots of examples/problems, I’m not sure what sort of advice you’re looking for. If you find Matsumura difficult to read, try picking up a different book.

Comment: You can try to read also Kaplansky's *Commutative Rings* and *Fields and Rings*.

Comment: There are few books about algebra (or any mathematics, for that matter) that I can recommend more highly than "Introduction to Commutative Algebra" by Atiyah and Macdonald. Worth its weight in gold.